# Inequality about Hadamard product

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, inequality

Let $X, Y\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Is the following inequality true?
$$2\|(X\odot Y)v\|\leq \|(X\odot X)v\|+\|(Y\odot Y)v\|$$
where $\odot$ is the Hadamard product and $\|\|$ is the Euclidean norm.

If it is not, is it true when $\|X\|_{op}\leq1, \|Y\|_{op}\leq1, \|v\|=1$?
What if we require $n<m$?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. Check out $X = \tfrac 1{\sqrt 2}(1,1)$, $Y= \tfrac 1{\sqrt 2}(1,-1)$ and $v = \tfrac 1{\sqrt 2}(1,-1)^T$.

Comment: What if we require $n<m$?

Comment: @neverevernever First of all, you are very welcome. As to your question: well, what do you think?

Comment: Thanks! I have no idea and that's why I ask...

Comment: Your inequality only holds for $n=1$. Otherwise you can always pad zeros to my above example.